# Elastic search find all documents contain word on a field

Tags: elasticsearch

i would like to know how can i search all my documents that have a string field which contains a word.

I was looking on a solution that uses wildcard with * before and after the word.
but its not good, since it also retrieve a documents that contains bigger word that contains that string.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html
i.e if i search for a "news"
result can contains "Wikinews" which is not what i wanted.

My index is defined like that :

```
PUT /index
{
   "mappings" : {
          "text" : {
             "properties" : {
                "text" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
                "url" : { "type" : "string"}
             }
          }
   }
}
```

I would like to search for documents that a given word would be on the 'text' field
EDIT :
example Data :

```
 curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/1' -d '
{ 
   "url": "wikipedia.com", 
   "Text": "in the news", 

}'

 curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/2' -d '
{ 
   "url": "wikipedia.com", 
   "Text": "Click here for Wikinews", 

}'

 curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/3' -d '
{ 
   "url": "wikipedia.com", 
   "Text": "news for each page are those:", 

}'


curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/4' -d '
{ 
   "url": "wikipedia.com", 
   "Text": "What are the news means to you", 

}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/5' -d '
{ 
   "url": "walla.com", 
   "Text": "today News are more ...", 

}'
```

This should return documents 1,3,4,5
document 5 because search is not case sensitive.
document 2 not included because it's not the word news it's part of bigger word which is not relevant

Thanks for helpers

Comment: What does a sample of your data set look like?  I assume the word news isn't in the field text alone.

Comment: could you please provide more information regarding kind of query you would like to perform, the results you want and results you want to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to remove `"index" : "not_analyzed"` because you need case insensitive search. `"index" : "not_analyzed"` will index the word as it is and you search for word "news" wont give you document 5.

```
{
   "mappings" : {
          "text" : {
             "properties" : {
                "text" : { "type" : "string"},
                "url" : { "type" : "string"}
             }
          }
   }
}
```

I am using default [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) as I have not specified any analyzers. You can learn more about ElasticSearch Analysis [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html).

After that a simple `match query` will be enough to get all desired documents.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "news"
    }
  }
}
```

You can replace match query with `match_phrase` query if you want phrase search.